# What word can be used for one who values the original version of literature over the altered one?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology

I'm wanting to refer to someone who would not appreciate anyone overlooking the fact that monks altered *Beowulf* and I'm wanting to say "be sensitive to the originalists" when speaking about Christian elements in the poem; however, "originalists" is term existent and referring to constitutional opinions, so I can't use that, right? I don't think traditionalist feels right either but maybe that's all I have.

Comment: *Beowulf* shows, IMO, two waves of Christian influence, the earlier syncretic, blending Christian and pagan views of justice and virtue, the later demonizing pagan beliefs and practices. So the situation is rather more complicated than an "originally pagan poem" monkeyed with by monks.

Comment: But I suppose you could  use "pagan-traditionalists" to refer to those who  regard *all* of the monotheistic elements as unoriginal and monkish meddling.

Comment: Couldn't you just call them *historians*?

Comment: *virginista*?...

Comment: *Historians* doesn't convey any sense of the preference for the (putative?)  "original" oral poem that  is adapted and changes by later poets.

Comment: The term 'original manuscripts' is unequivocal; 'faithful to the original manuscripts' is stricter than 'sensitive to ...' (_how_ sensitive?), but would require say '... frown upon the fact that Christian monks who relayed _Beowulf_ edited to produce a version not faithful to the original manuscripts'.

Answer (score 1):

**Purist** - according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purist): "a person who adheres strictly and often excessively to a tradition".

Its page quotes the *Washington Post* in 2023: "The rock music in this production will, no doubt, make a buzzkill out of the Shakespeare purist." Here referring to somebody who's excessively concerned about authenticity and tradition in Shakespeare plays.

Comment: Perhaps over-broad; 'fundamentalist' certainly carries too much baggage.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you *can* try *originalist*; [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/originalist) gives the sense:

> One who aims to discover how the writers of a document intended it to
> be interpreted, and to interpret it in that way.

Comment: This is the definition given in most dictionaries; it is the original _interpretation_ / _understanding of a document's meaning at the time of writing_ rather than the original  form of language (so archaic words and forms are validly updated if the original sense is retained/reinstated) that is considered crucial.